# How do I enable incremental repair on Cassandra 2.1.13?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

I want to enable incremental repairs on Cassandra 2.1.13?. [This mailing list post](http://grokbase.com/t/cassandra/user/15c14gqc0c/transitioning-to-incremental-repair#20151201bgbfq6kagg3jesbqnb3hyxdte8) states

> Yes, it should now be safe to just run a repair with -inc -par to migrate
>   to incremental repairs

. However, Datastax documentation [states](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/opsRepairNodesMigration.html) a six step checklist is required.

Is it fine to simply do `nodetool repair -inc -par`? Are there any risks? The checklist worries me since a full repair can take a really long time and I risk getting timeouts if I have many small sstables due to compaction being disabled.

Comment: Do you have OpsCenter connected to the DSE cluster?

Comment: Yes, but I'd prefer to use vanilla Cassandra features.

Comment: First off I would not use -par with -inc.  There is a lot that can go wrong with that.  I would point out [this really good blog post by The Last Pickle](http://www.slideshare.net/DataStax/real-world-tales-of-repair-alexander-dejanovski-the-last-pickle-cassandra-summit-2016) on the subject of different kinds of repair.

Comment: Here's the [video of that presentation](https://youtu.be/1Sz_K8UID6E)